# How to find out which URI is the online help URI?

Tags: powershell

I have a function/cmdlet with multiple links like this:

```
function MyFunc
{
    <#
        .LINK
        https://google.com/
        .LINK
        https://yahoo.com/
    #>
}
```

Any link that's just a URL shows up as `uri` objects under `(Get-Help).relatedLinks.navigationLink.uri`. But I believe PowerShell by default uses the first one as the online help URI (`Get-Help -Online` goes to google.com).

Is there an existing property that identifies which `uri` is used as the online help URI? I believe simply selecting the first `uri` will usually work (`(Get-Help).relatedLinks.navigationLink.uri[0]`), but I was wondering if there's a dedicated property for that purpose?

Comment: `Get-Command MyFunc | Select-Object -ExpandProperty HelpUri`